# dump the yaml to a variable instead of streaming it in stdout using ruamel.yaml

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am not able to find a way to dump the YAML to a variable in ruamel.yaml. With PyYAML, I could able to achieve the same like below:

```
with open('oldPipeline.yml','r') as f:
    data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

a = yaml.dump(data)
```

But when I try the same with `ruamel.yaml`, it throws the exception `TypeError: Need a stream argument when not dumping from context manager`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error clearly indicates you should provide a stream, so you should just do that:

```
import io
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = b"""\
fact: The recommended YAML file extension has been .yaml since September 2006
origin: yaml.org FAQ
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
buf = io.BytesIO()
yaml.dump(data, buf)
assert buf.getvalue() == yaml_str
```

which gives no assertion error.

ruamel.yaml and PyYAML use a stream interface and writing this to a buffer is
seldom necessary and should be avoided because of its inefficiency, especially
in the often seen PyYAML form of:

```
print(yaml.dump(data))  # inefficient wrt time and space
```

instead of the more appropriate

```
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Post-processing of the the output should preferably be done in a stream like
object, or by using the `transform` option described in the [Basic
Usage](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basicuse.html?highlight=transform#basic-usage)
section of the documentation.

The is further explained [here](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html?highlight=StringIO#output-of-dump-as-a-string), and of course you could also have
looked up how PyYAML does this.

Comment: Got it - I was not aware of `BytesIO`; Thanks for this.